# jQuery: Importing a single plugin

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using both jQuery and Bootstrap on my Django site. Since I've been having issues with conflicts between the two modules, I've identified the specific functions that I want from each module and imported them separately:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="/static/js/jquery/src/effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="/static/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="/static/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
```

The site seems to run fine, but I'm concerned about the *ReferenceError: Can't find variable: define* error that results from not importing the entire jQuery module.

Should I try to fix this error if the site is functional? Is there a specific file I should be importing before `effects.js`? Or should I be using a different approach to the problem?

Comment: type="text/JavaScript" is missing from the effects.js

Comment: All right, I changed it. It's unrelated to the problem, though.

Comment: Text/JavaScript is no longer needed since htlm5